# Change Custom Domain Name in Azure AD

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-web-apps

Although we haven't created the Azure AD infrastructure yet and I'm a bit new to the Azure world, a question has come up regarding the simplicity of changing a custom domain name in an Azure tenant.

Say our tenant is:

```
widgetsAreUs.com
```

The custom domain would be something like:

```
test.widgetsAreUs.com
```

How difficult is it to change that custom domain name to something like this, and what are the implications/impacts thereof?

```
spinoff.widgetsAreUs.com
```

Was looking at this [post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/domains-manage), but the answer wasn't entirely clear to me, except that we may need to add a new custom domain and delete the old one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple custom domain names for each tenant, so adding another one is simple, you just add it and confirm ownership.

Making it the default is a little more complicated. You can change it to default in the UI, but you may then have to go through existing users and change their upn suffix if you want to use that.